# How to force a certain python version during a macports install

Tags: python, macports

I am installing a package on macports (ocaml) which is failing because one of the dependencies won't install with python 3.5 (which I have reported as a bug). 
The maintainer says it works with python2.7

Can I temporarily tell macports to use python2.7 for the install, instead of the more cumbersome approach of changing the default python version just for this install?

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts packages multiple Python versions that can be installed side-by-side. See the `python27` and `python35` ports that provide Python 2.7 and 3.5, respectively.

MacPorts itself does not have the notion of a "default python", its packages always explicitly depend on a specific version of Python. The port that fails to install may be a python module (usually in the form of py35-something), in which case you should check for the py27-something version of it. If it is not a python module, it may offer variants to select the python version you want to use. See the output of `port variants $portname` for a list of available variants.

You should probably also file a ticket for this problem in the MacPorts bug tracker.